# Rails: Having trouble adding sorting to a column on a view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add sorting to these columns using an existing application helper. I'd like to add the ability to add sorting to the "status" and "name" columns, but I cannot get it to function. The links appear but the sorting doesn't happen. I've been toying with this for days and now I'm hoping someone can help me get on track.

[image]

**The application helper:**

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, request.parameters.merge({ sort: column, direction: direction, page: nil }), { class: css_class }
  end

  def sort_params(column, direction)
    allowed = %i[
      search tag_id tag_name
      utf8 
      filter_tag_id
      direction sort commit
    ]
    params.permit(allowed).merge(sort: column, direction: direction)
  end
end
```

(The rendered link is `<a href="/broadcasts/530?direction=desc&sort=status">Status</a>`)

**Show:**

```
 <table class="table1">
    <thead class="thead1">
      <tr class="tr1">
        <th class="th1">Number</th>
        <th class="th1"><%= sortable "name", "Name" %></th>
        <th class="th1"><%= sortable "status", "Status" %></th>
        <th class="th1">Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="tbody1">
      <% @uniq_contacts.include?(nil) ? @uniq_contacts : @uniq_contacts.uniq! %>
      <% @uniq_contacts.each do |contact|%>

        <tr class="tr1">
          <td class="td1">
            <% if contact.blank? %>
              <p class="font-italic mb-0">Deleted</p>
            <% else %>  
              <%= Contact.to_us contact.number%>
            <% end %>  
          </td>

          <td class="td1">
            <% if contact.blank? %>
              <p class="font-italic mb-0">Deleted</p>
            <% else %>  
              <%= contact.first_name %>
              <%= contact.last_name %>
            <% end %>  
          </td>

          <td class="td1" id="contact-id-<%= contact&.id %>">
            <%= @broadcast.messages.find_by(contact: contact)&.status %>
          </td>

          <td class="td1">
            <% if @broadcast.updated_at > Time.now - 1.year %>
              <%= @broadcast.updated_at.strftime('%b %e %l:%M %P') %>
            <% else %>
              <%= @broadcast.updated_at.strftime('%b %e, %Y %l:% %P') %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Controller method:**

```
  def sort_column
    @broadcast.messages.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "status"
  end
  
  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

**schema:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sort_column` method:

```
@broadcast.messages.column_names
```

Does it include `name`? If not, there's your problem.